# FreeMarker error on Android Studio while creating new Activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Recently, I had updated Android Studio to 3.4.0. Back then, I had no problems and everything was working just fine. But after I had updated to 3.4.0, I've been constantly getting this error message while trying to create a new activity using the built-in wizard. How would I be able to fix this issue? Here's a stack trace of the error:

```
Error executing FreeMarker template

FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> manifestDir  [in template "root://activities/common/common_globals.xml.ftl" at line 38, column 39]

Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally null/missing, either specify a default value with myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthessis: (myOptionVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionVar.foo)??

The failing instruction (FTL stack trace):
----------
==> ${manifestDir}  [in template "root://activities/common/common_globals.xml.ftl" at line 38, column 37]
    #include "../common/common_globals.xm...  [in template "root://activities/EmptyActivity/globals.xml.ftl" at line 8, column 5]
----------

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----------
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:98)
    at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToString(EvalUtil.java:382)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:115)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1712)
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:172)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:243)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:277)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils.processFreemarkerTemplate(FreemarkerUtils.java:98)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.processFile(Template.java:504)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.access$100(Template.java:82)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$3.startElement(Template.java:546)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.processXml(Template.java:517)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.processFile(Template.java:501)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.lambda$doRender$2(Template.java:401)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$1.run(Template.java:379)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$null$1(WriteCommandAction.java:264)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1057)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:263)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:321)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:188)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:323)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:262)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:244)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.runWriteCommandAction(Template.java:381)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.doRender(Template.java:400)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.render(Template.java:243)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.RenderTemplateModel$FreeMarkerTemplateRenderer.renderTemplate(RenderTemplateModel.java:344)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.RenderTemplateModel$FreeMarkerTemplateRenderer.doDryRun(RenderTemplateModel.java:260)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer.countDown(MultiTemplateRenderer.java:156)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer.requestRender(MultiTemplateRenderer.java:120)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.RenderTemplateModel.handleFinished(RenderTemplateModel.java:208)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:403)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:331)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:311)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1831)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6548)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4903)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:755)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:700)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:391)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:698)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:430)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1681)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1630)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.NewAndroidComponentAction.actionPerformed(NewAndroidComponentAction.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:258)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:275)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:287)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:283)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:106)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:277)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:522)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:35)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:544)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6548)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4903)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:755)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:700)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:391)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines in the project Gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if (osName.contains("windows")) {
        buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    }
```

Remove it and sync then everything will work OK.